# My M4A file will not play with jPlayer

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I'm trying to figure out how jPlayer works.  I followed all the instructions but my M4A file will not play.

Here is my code.

```
<link type="text/css" href="/skin/circle.skin/circle.player.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transform2d.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.grab.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mod.csstransforms.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/circle.player.js"></script>
<script src="js/flac.js"></script>
<script src="js/ogg.js"></script>
<script src="js/vorbis.js"></script>
<script src="js/opus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var myOtherOne = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_2",
        {
            m4a:"http://www.rcsoundbox.com/real_teaser.m4a",
            m4a:"http://www.rcsoundbox.com/real_teaser.m4a"
        }, {
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_2"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `m4a:"http://...` twice? What's that for?

Comment: Can you post a minimal HTML code sample?

Answer (score 0):

.....Open your .m4a file: http://www.rcsoundbox.com/real_teaser.m4a

[image]

now open this .m4a file: http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-04-Lismore.m4a

[image]

*(Notice any difference? I do in FF v.34)*

Long answer short: use a properly formatted file, and use jPlayer properly:

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/gtxjw723/)***

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer_2"></div>

<div id="cp_container_2" class="cp-container">
    <div class="cp-buffer-holder">
        <div class="cp-buffer-1"></div>
        <div class="cp-buffer-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cp-progress-holder">
        <div class="cp-progress-1"></div>
        <div class="cp-progress-2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cp-circle-control"></div>
    <ul class="cp-controls">
        <li><a class="cp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
        <li><a class="cp-pause" style="display:none;" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
    var myOtherOne = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_2",{
        m4a:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-04-Lismore.m4a",
        oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04-Lismore.ogg"
    }, {
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_2"
    });
});
```